# Selecting path, changing opacity based on legend mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

This, I think, is basically a selection question.

Here's my [semi-working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mvdqBPMymCt9VAKAPKD1?p=preview).

I'm trying to select a path, and change the opacity of all paths within a chart that are *not* selected, based on a mouseover of the respective graphic element (a circle) in the chart's legend.

I've set the id of the paths such they'll have the same id as the circles that are activated on mouseover. I've also gotten the circles that are not selected on hover to change opacity. (Currently, however, all of the non-selected circles, in all of the legends, across all of the charts, change opacity. I'm trying to limit mouseover opacity changes to only the relevant chart.)

What I'm trying to achieve:
When I mouseover a circle in the legend of a given chart, the same opacity changes should be applied to the paths of that chart, as if I had hovered over the paths themselves. If I understand my problem correctly, I'm having trouble defining the selection/non-selection of the circles and their respective paths, and limiting those selections to only one chart out of several on the page.

Here's how the paths' groups and ids are defined:

```
  var pathGroup = main.append('g').classed('paths', true);
  var paths = pathGroup.selectAll("path")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("id", function(d) {
      return d.record
    })    
    .attr("data-legend", function(d) {
      return d.record
    })
```

And here's the problematic code, I think:

```
  li.selectAll("circle")
    .attr("id",function (d) {return d.key})        
    .style("fill",function(d) { return d.value.color})
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    // need to define "circleGroup" and "circles" (as is done for "pathGroup" and "paths") so that the legend's non-selected circles are the ones that fade)
    // also need to find a way of limiting "circles" to a circle group within only that state's chart 
    //          circles
          d3.selectAll('circle:not(this)')
          .style('opacity', 0.4)
          .style('transition', "opacity 0.1s")
        d3.select(this)
          .classed('hover', true)
          .style('opacity', 0.9)
          .style('transition', "opacity 0.1s")

  d3.select('path:not(this)')
    .style('opacity', 0.4)
    .style('transition', "opacity 0.1s")
  //      d3.select('path data-legend',  function(d) { return d.key})
  d3.select('path id',  function(d) { return d.key})
    .classed('hover', true)
    .style('opacity', 0.9)
    .style('transition', "opacity 0.1s")              
  })
      .on('mouseout', function(d) {
        d3.selectAll('circle')
          .style('opacity', 0.9)
          .style('transition', "opacity 0.1s")
      })
```

Here, again, is my semi-working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mvdqBPMymCt9VAKAPKD1?p=preview

In advance, thanks for any help you can offer in setting this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues** with your code:

> d3.selectAll('circle')
>   selects all the circles in the body and as far as the paths are concerned:
>
> d3.select('path id') wouldn't work as the selector itself is messed up here. Try console logging the selection here.

**Option 1:**

Try replacing the legend mouse events with the following code:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    // look for all the circles within the parent node
    d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll('circle').style('opacity', 0.4);

    // change opacity of current circle
    d3.select(this).style('opacity', 0.9);

    // use parentNode to go until SVG and select all paths
    d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode).select('g.paths').selectAll('path').style('opacity', 0.4);

    // change opacity of path with data-legend = key
    d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode).select('g.paths').selectAll('path[data-legend="'+d.key+'"]').style('opacity', 0.9);
 })
.on('mouseout', function(d) {
  // change all circles' and paths' opacity back to original values
    d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll('circle').style('opacity', 0.9);
    d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode).select('g.paths').selectAll('path').style('opacity', 0.9);
});
```

I hope the comments are clear enough to understand the code. Just parsing through the parentNodes.

**Option 2:**

Add a class/id to the legend group representing the "state" i.e. Alabama, California etc.

And search for the SVG with selectedState on every mouseover and change the paths' opacity.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: It's beautiful! Thank you. I was going to completely rewrite the legend, but this is an elegant solution.

Comment: Have fun coding! Glad to help! :)